# How to clear focus from spinner in android?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-dialog

While clicking the spinner to show the spinner drop down and one dialog. while press the single back button, i have to exit from spinner and dialog show. How to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If by single back button you mean the main back button then you will have to override the onBackPressed() method as below

```
     @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
  invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Then in your onPrepareOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     spinner.clearFocus();   
    return true;
}
```

Try this.

Comment: Sorry one thing i forget to mention here. I set the spinner in Action Bar Activity menu. While click the action bar menu to show the one dialog and spinner drop down. press the single back button i have to exit from dialog and spinner, Now single press exit from dialog alone

Comment: While press the single back button to dismiss dialog and clear spinner focus

Comment: Please post your onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected codes

Comment: getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
String[] value = {city};
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,value);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
  dialog.show();
  return false; }});
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
   dialog.dismiss();}
  return true; }});

Comment: I have changed the answer. Try it out. If it doesn't work then i am afraid i cant help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105973/discussion-between-saravanan-selvam-and-ragesh-ramesh).